# Ajax call slower in MySQL than MS Sql

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

I'm displaying map in a website with markers. I get the location from mysql database using a servlet and get it in js.

```
 function initMap() {
     getLocationFromServlet(xhr); //get 
     setTimeout(function() {

         createMap(); //create map after getting coord from getLocationFromServlet(xhr), but latArray is empty

         console.log(latArray); //empty here though defined in getLocationFromServlet
     }, 1300);
 }

 function createMap() {
     var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
     map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv);
     map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(latArray[0], lngArray[0]));
     map.setZoom(17);

     createMarker();

     setTimeout(function() {
         console.log(latArray);
     }, 1600)
 }

 function createMarker() {
     latArray.forEach(function(lat, i) {
         var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
             content: '<div id="content>' + '<p style="color:#000000">DeviceID:<p>' + '<p>' + deviceId[i] + '</p>' + '</div>'
         });
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             map: map,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
             //position: new google.maps.LatLng(latArray[i], lngArray[i]),
             icon: "phone6.png"
         });
         markerArray.push(marker);
         markerArray[i].setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(latArray[i], lngArray[i]));
         markerArray[i].addListener("click", function() {
             infoWindow.open(map, marker);
         });
     });
     console.log(latArray);
 }

 function getLocationFromServlet(xhr) {
     xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open('POST', 'GetLocationFromDB', true);
     xhr.send();
     xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
         console.log(xhr.readyState == 4); // false twice in console.log, but I call the function only once
         if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
             data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
             //console.log(data);
             if (latArrayCount != 1) {
                 latArray.length = 0;
                 lngArray.length = 0;
                 deviceId.length = 0;
             } else {
                 latArrayCount++;
             }
             for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                 if (!((i + 1) % 3 == 0)) {
                     //console.log(data);
                     latArray.push(data[i]);
                     lngArray.push(data[i + 1]);
                     deviceId.push(data[i + 2]);
                     i = i + 2;
                     console.log("lat" + latArray);
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     console.log(latArray); //displayed empty twice before displaying latArray values
 }
```

This code works in ms sql. In mysql i see values in console only after few falses above the console in `if (xhr.readyState == 4)`

Comment: None of this code has anything to do with MS SQL or MySQL...

Comment: @David. hows it working in MS SQL

Comment: @boo: That sounds like something you'd need to debug and examine in some way.  Maybe your server-side code is behaving differently, maybe your queries are behaving differently, maybe your database is structured differently, etc.  But if you're having a problem with server-side resources, only looking at the client-side code in the browser isn't going to get you very far.

Comment: @Andy ok..but i cant create the map